# How to force Gnu screen to load my bash .profile

Tags: macos, command-line, gnu-screen

I have ~/.bash_profile which I would like to be invoked every single time a new GNU screen is created so that all my aliases work in GNU screen as they work in terminal.

At this time this is what my ~/.screenrc looks like.

```
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %m/%d %C%a "
```

Comment: I solved this problem by moving all the contents of ~/.bash_profile to ~/.bashrc. Apparently screen invokes ~/.bashrc before each window.

Answer (score 40):

`shell -$SHELL`

Add the above line to your `~/.screenrc`, this will make screen start-up using a login shell which will load your `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: This stops screen starting in the current directory. How do I make screen start in the current directory?

Answer (score 3):

Some Mac applications rely on .bash_profile and some on .bashrc. I have not figured out any particular rule for knowning which one is getting loaded but for consistency this is my .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Debian and Ubuntu (at least), in their standard configuration, have a **/etc/profile.d/** directory from which any containing file ending by **.sh** are sourced by **/etc/profile**.

This is very practical for adding configurations, but makes users thinking this is the proper place for dropping their new settings, whereas this is not always true.

I don't understand why they didn't do the same for **/etc/bash.bashrc**, I hope they will do it in some future, but in the meantime, I did it myself:

1. Create a new directory at **/etc/bash.bashrc.d/**
2. Similarly to what exists in **/etc/profile**, add the following lines at the end of **/etc/bash.bashrc**:

   ```
   if test -d /etc/bash.bashrc.d/; then
       for bashrc in /etc/bash.bashrc.d/*.sh; do
           test -r "$bashrc" && . "$bashrc"
       done
       unset bashrc
   fi
   ```
3. Starting from now, drop files needed for non-interactive shells in **/etc/bash.bashrc.d/** rather than in **/etc/profile.d/**.

That way, the only change needed to existing files is at the end of **/etc/bash.bashrc**.

I think this is the main reasons for users complaining about their profile not loaded, but actually their profile may not **NEED** to be loaded.

Maybe you could read **[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells)** about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a little vague; shell startup files are run by screen upon creation of windows, that yours aren't feels like something is misconfigured in your .bashrc or .bash_profile. I haven't run into this using screen on OS X.

Have you tried [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) instead of screen? I use it exclusively on my Mac and then use screen on the servers I admin.

Answer (score 0):

> I solved this problem by moving all the contents of ~/.bash_profile to ~/.bashrc. Apparently screen invokes ~/.bashrc before each window. – Nadal May 6 '10 at 21:22

This comment is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added a .bashrc file that just contains:

```
[[ -s ~/.bash_profile ]] && source ~/.bash_profile
```

This way any program such as GNU screen that looks for .bashrc will find it, and source my .bash_profile.